# CoreBluetooth Advertising but cannot see from other device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, swift3, core-bluetooth

I was trying to setup an iOS iPhone as a Bluetooth Peripheral so I could see it from another iDevice the Bluetooth device and send information.

I think I am advertising myself but I cannot see it any where from either another iPhone, iPad or Mac.  The console output suggests it is advertising ? Am I missing something obvious, (I have looked around, Googled and here) but no luck.

Console:

```
self.peripheralManager powered on.
Service Added
peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(_:error:)
Advertising
```

Code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
class ViewController: UIViewController,CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    var peripheralManager:CBPeripheralManager!
    var transferCharacteristic: CBMutableCharacteristic?
    let MyP_Service_UUID = CBUUID(string: "1B981746-2064-4F68-BBB8-69A185314FC6")
    let MyP_Characteristics_UUID = CBUUID(string: "4271CEC1-652D-489B-8484-7C3550C6075E")
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        // Don't keep it going while we're not showing.
        peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
    }
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        if (peripheral.state != .poweredOn) {
            return
        }
        print("self.peripheralManager powered on.")
        // ... so build our service.
        let myCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: MyP_Characteristics_UUID, properties: [.notify], value: nil, permissions: .readable)
        let myService = CBMutableService(type: MyP_Service_UUID, primary: true)
        myService.characteristics?.append(myCharacteristic)
        peripheralManager.add(myService)
        peripheralManager.startAdvertising([ CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [MyP_Service_UUID], CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : "MyP"])
    }

    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAdd service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        print(error ?? "Service Added")
    }
    func peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, error: Error?) {
        print(#function)
        print(error ?? "Advertising")
    }
    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, central: CBCentral, didSubscribeTo characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
        print(#function)
    }
    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, central: CBCentral, didUnsubscribeFrom characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
        print(#function)
    }
    func peripheralManagerIsReady(toUpdateSubscribers peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        print(#function)
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you trying to see the advertising device?  Are you using your own code or an app such as LightBlue

Comment: I think I understand it now. I would need another device listening for my advertisement as it is BLE. So it does not show up in standard Bluetooth devices. Probably I should delete this question!

Answer (score 1):

For better support we need to see your code on the BLE Central side. Are you scanning for the same service UUIDs on your scanning device?

By the way, depending on your use case you might want to check other SDKs that can handle all the bluetooth interaction for you. 
For example: MultipeerConnectivity, p2pkit, google nearby.

Disclaimer:
I work on the team that has developed p2pkit

Answer (score 0):

I was too much of a newbie and didn't understand how BLE work. I now see I need to advertise the correct services etc, then other devices will subscribe.

I initially expected to see it in the Bluetooth pairing screen of my iPhone.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can not see your on own advertising device on your device bluetooth list.